# Arabic text in Excel sheets

Tags: excel, hyperlink, whatsapp, arabic

I'm trying to create hyperlinks to certain people using Whatsapp API in Excel. The English texts go through but the Arabic ones don't.

`=HYPERLINK("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone="&B2&"&text="&A2, "Send")`

A2 containing Arabic text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.